# MySQL - importing HUGE csv using 'load data infile"

Tags: mysql, csv

I need some help.
I have created my table structure as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_data` (
`Date` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
`test1` double,
`check1` int,
`test2` double,
`check2` int,
`No` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(No)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

my csv data is huge 5gb files and above. It captures data every second. The data might be the same for each second but the information is valid. How do I import all of the duplicates? the system when I tried to use the below command, keeps eliminating the duplicates.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/mydatatable.csv' INTO TABLE my_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

here is the sample records of the csv

```html
<style>
 .demo {
  border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  padding:5px;
 }
 .demo th {
  border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
  padding:5px;
  background:#F0F0F0;
 }
 .demo td {
  border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
  padding:5px;
 }
</style>
<table class="demo">
 <caption>Table 1</caption>
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th>date/time</th>
  <th>A</th>
  <th>B</th>
  <th>C</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>2/23/2015 0:42</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2/23/2015 0:42</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2/23/2015 0:42</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>​
```

CSV Data:

```
2/23/2015 0:42,3,4,2
2/23/2015 0:42,3,4,2
2/23/2015 0:42,3,4,2
```

Comment: I am confused. What is your csv? You are showing html. Also, your schema has a primary key on `No`. How are you expecting duplicates to appear?

Comment: @Drew The html is a representation, I added the csv data in an edit. `NO` as the primary key column in the CSV data doesn't exist, in order to auto increment the imported data. EG same as `... IGNORE 1 LINES (DATE, test1, check1, test2, check2)`

Comment: Primary keys must be unique!

Comment: @AdmiralNoiseBottom primary keys are not being inserted, 5 columns in CSV, 6 columns in database table.

Comment: Apologies, at a glance I thought I spotted values going in. Perhaps I should wear my glasses more often. :)

Comment: Do you have triggers on the table that may alter the data being inserted?

Comment: Do you find any of the answers to your questions helpful so you can accept answers on them (like the guy below not mine) or on any of your other questions? People took the time to answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am unable to reproduce the issue, are you sure your lines are terminated by `\n` and not `\r\n`?

Firstly I would try to move the `auto_increment` column as the first column.

```
ALTER TABLE `my_data`
    CHANGE COLUMN `NO` `NO` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

Then I explicitly define the columns so that they are represented correctly from the imported data, rather than implied.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/mydatatable.csv' 
    IGNORE INTO TABLE `my_data` 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES (`DATE`, `test1`, `check1`, `test2`, `check2`);
```

This will ensure if there is any extra column data in your CSV, it will be ignored in order to ensure that the `auto_increment` column is not being tainted with `''` or `0` etc.

**End Result**

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/mydatatable.csv'
    -> IGNORE INTO TABLE `test`.`my_data`
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 LINES (`DATE`, `test1`, `check1`, `test2`, `check2`);
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.04 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 3
```

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                    |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1261 | Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 2 doesn't contain data for all columns |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 3 doesn't contain data for all columns |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM my_data;
+----+----------------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
| NO | DATE           | test1 | check1 | test2 | check2 |
+----+----------------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
|  1 | 2/23/2015 0:42 |     3 |      4 |     2 |   NULL |
|  2 | 2/23/2015 0:42 |     3 |      4 |     2 |   NULL |
|  3 | 2/23/2015 0:42 |     3 |      4 |     2 |   NULL |
+----+----------------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```